# Jdialog disappears before usable

Tags: java, jdialog

I have a strange problem: From a MenuBar I (or the user) can call two actions. One does importing some data, the other deletes some data. Both are presented through a JDialog. Now the weird thing is that both share effectively the same layout and yet while the import dialogue works perfectly, the delete dialogue vanished before any interaction can happen. I do call them seperately.

For comparison consider these parts:

- the Import dialogue

```
 JDialog ImportFenster= new JDialog(Fenster,
                    "Import von Nutzern");

            JTextField Name= new JTextField("Vorname [Leer] Name",30);
            JFormattedTextField ID =new JFormattedTextField(
                    NumberFormat.getIntegerInstance());
            ID.setColumns(8);

            JButton Enter = new JButton("OK");
            JButton Abort =new JButton("Abbruch");
            JLabel InfoID= new JLabel("Wird keine ID angegeben, wird eine automatisch erzeugt");

            GridBagLayout ImportLayout= new GridBagLayout();
            GridBagConstraints LayoutConstraints=new GridBagConstraints();

            ImportFenster.setLayout(ImportLayout);

            LayoutConstraints.fill=GridBagConstraints.VERTICAL;
            LayoutConstraints.gridwidth=3;
            LayoutConstraints.gridx=0;
            LayoutConstraints.gridy=0;
            LayoutConstraints.ipadx=5;
            LayoutConstraints.ipady=5;
            ImportFenster.add(InfoID,LayoutConstraints);
            LayoutConstraints.gridwidth=1;
            LayoutConstraints.ipadx=10;
            LayoutConstraints.ipady=25;
            LayoutConstraints.gridx=1;
            LayoutConstraints.gridy=1;
            ImportFenster.add(ID,LayoutConstraints);
            LayoutConstraints.ipadx=10;
            LayoutConstraints.ipady=25;
            LayoutConstraints.gridx=1;
            LayoutConstraints.gridy=2;
            ImportFenster.add(Name,LayoutConstraints);
            LayoutConstraints.ipadx=10;
            LayoutConstraints.ipady=25;
            LayoutConstraints.gridx=3;
            LayoutConstraints.gridy=3;
            ImportFenster.add(Enter,LayoutConstraints);
            LayoutConstraints.ipadx=10;
            LayoutConstraints.ipady=25;
            LayoutConstraints.gridx=0;
            LayoutConstraints.gridy=3;
            ImportFenster.add(Abort,LayoutConstraints);
            LayoutConstraints.gridx=0;
            LayoutConstraints.gridy=1;
            ImportFenster.add(new JLabel("Nutzer-ID:"),LayoutConstraints);
            LayoutConstraints.gridx=0;
            LayoutConstraints.gridy=2;
            ImportFenster.add(new JLabel("Nutzer-Name:"),LayoutConstraints);


            ImportFenster.setSize(750,350);
            ImportFenster.setVisible(true);
```

- the delete dialogue

```
JDialog EntfernenFenster= new JDialog(Fenster,
                        "Löschen von Nutzern");
                JFormattedTextField ID =new JFormattedTextField(
                        NumberFormat.getIntegerInstance());
                ID.setColumns(8);
                System.out.println("Dialog:"+EntfernenFenster.isShowing());
                JButton Enter = new JButton("OK");
                JButton Abort =new JButton("Abbruch");
                System.out.println("Knöppe sind da:"+Enter.isShowing()+"\t"+Abort.isShowing());
                GridBagLayout EntfernenLayout= new GridBagLayout();
                EntfernenFenster.setLayout(EntfernenLayout);
                GridBagConstraints LayoutConstraints=new GridBagConstraints();
                LayoutConstraints.fill=GridBagConstraints.VERTICAL;
                LayoutConstraints.gridwidth=1;
                LayoutConstraints.ipadx=10;
                LayoutConstraints.ipady=25;
                LayoutConstraints.gridx=1;
                LayoutConstraints.gridy=1;
                EntfernenFenster.add(ID,LayoutConstraints);
                LayoutConstraints.ipadx=10;
                LayoutConstraints.ipady=25;
                LayoutConstraints.gridx=0;
                LayoutConstraints.gridy=1;
                EntfernenFenster.add(new JLabel("Nutzer-ID:"));
                LayoutConstraints.ipadx=10;
                LayoutConstraints.ipady=25;
                LayoutConstraints.gridx=2;
                LayoutConstraints.gridy=2;
                EntfernenFenster.add(Enter,LayoutConstraints);
                LayoutConstraints.ipadx=10;
                LayoutConstraints.ipady=25;
                LayoutConstraints.gridx=0;
                LayoutConstraints.gridy=2;
                EntfernenFenster.add(Abort,LayoutConstraints);

                EntfernenFenster.setSize(500, 200);
                EntfernenFenster.setVisible(true);
```

I would like to know where my mistake is. And of course how to fix this.

Comment: The call site is important too. Whether called as `SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> showDialog());` or immediately.

Comment: I mean, it is called from within an ActionListener. Otherwise I don't know what you mean. @JoopEggen

Comment: You could try to move the code of the ActionListenerer's actionPerformed to a new method `void showEntfernenFenster()` and do `SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> showEntfernenFenster());`.

Comment: that actually did the trick thank you! why did this work?

Answer (score 0):

You could try to move the code of the ActionListenerer's actionPerformed to a new method `void showEntfernenFenster()` and do

```
SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> showEntfernenFenster());
```

For instance in:

```
JMenuItem menuItem = ...
menuItem.addActionListener(evt ->
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> showEntfernenFenster()));
```

`actionPerformed` happens on the single thread handling GUI events in the AWT queue. Then little else for the GUI can be done. `AWTEventQueue.invokeLater` or `SwingUtilities.invokeLater` (identical) will indeed call the passed "Runnable" after the `actionPerformed` is processed. And then again the GUI is responsive, redrawing etcetera, In general do not do long things in actionPerformed.

##### The why:

In order to redraw, invalidate multiple screen regions, and all in a non-parallel manner - sequentially -, many libraries across programming languages and even on operating system level use this simplifying technique: a queue of events and one thread handling them.